# crm 2011 creating a view of merged contacts

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

Can I create a view of the contacts that have been merged?
I want to include active and inactive (sub ordinate) contacts as well in the view.
I can search inactive contacts with the status 'Merged duplicates'.
How do I find the master record in which it has been merged?
Help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CRM has two fields called "merged" and "masterid" which indicate if the record was merged and the master record id. Unfortunately, CRM doesn't expose these fields so you won't be able to create a view but you can create a SSRS report to display merged records if you want.

The following is an example about how to retrieve this information using fetchXML:

```
<fetch>
  <entity name="contact" >
    <attribute name="fullname" />
    <attribute name="merged" />
    <attribute name="masterid" />
    <filter>
      <condition attribute="merged" operator="eq" value="1" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

[image]

Comment: I'd give a shot at putting the query in a view via manual customizations.xml editing, it might work

Comment: Thank you Federico! Worked for me!!

Comment: If you use the View Designer plugin (http://cinteros.xrmtoolbox.com/) for XRMToolbox you can insert this FetchXML as the query for a custom view and it will display correctly in CRM.

Answer (score 0):

You can't find all active contacts which were merged using advanced find. But it is possible to create a plugin to mark active records with some custom flag (Was Merged for example) or place a lookup for latest merged record ("Was merged with" for example) and then you can find all active records using advanced find. This can be helpfull during plugin creation: http://mscrm-chandan.blogspot.ru/2012/08/get-entity-details-in-merge-plugin.html

Comment: This would certainly help me in some other scenario, Thanks Marat!