# How to unmerge records which are merged from D365 OOB feature?

Tags: dynamics-crm, customization, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

How to unmerge records which are merged  from D365 OOB feature? Is there any custom code solution ?

Comment: Pls read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, un-merging cannot be achieved in any OOB option and AFAIK, no community solutions are available.

As this is totally a rare requirement, we can build some console app for this.

We know that the master record will get/copy all the subordinate record field values after merging (based on choice in Merge screen), the subordinate record will get deactivated (still holding its original field values only). All the related records will be remapped to master record. So we have to reverse engineer all this for un-merging.

[From my research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39830797/7920473), looks like the deactivated subordinate record will hold the master record as a link in `masterid` field. We have to pull all these records using the query below & iterate through each record, and then achieve what we want.

```
<fetch>
  <entity name="contact" >
    <attribute name="fullname" />
    <attribute name="merged" />
    <attribute name="masterid" />
    <filter>
      <condition attribute="merged" operator="eq" value="1" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: Agreed Arun, and getting the related records back seems to be the trickiest part. If Audit is turned on you could ostensibly parse the audit logs to find the prior parent records.

Comment: @Aron, was thinking about the same. Otherwise a better candidate for XrmToolBox plugin :)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion..how to identify which are fields data are merged and need to rollback those data ? Can you pls provide some sample code if possible.

Comment: @Krishna that’s too broad in SO. :) you have to pull the details from Audit if it’s available & put it back. In fact that’s a huge project.. start yourself from the above code & searching internet for audit samples, read lot of blogs for CRM basics & how to.